# can I prevent access to html pages with meteor auth?

Tags: meteor

I read in the documentation that meteor support user authorizations on database level
how can I use it to prevent users from accessing Html pages when not logged on ?
is it possible ?
thanks
jean-louis

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. Meteor 0.5.0 comes with a revised and fully loaded Accounts API. One way to enable access to this set of APIs in your app is to install the `accounts-password` package.

```
meteor add accounts-password
```

Manually create users using `Accounts.createUser` and log users in using `Meteor.loginWithPassword` (or one of many external authorization services available). Or just use the [accounts-ui](http://docs.meteor.com/#accountsui) feature to handle the authentication stuff automatically using a built-in login UI.

Once authentication part has been implemented, restrict access to your webpage (or parts of it) using a condition like:

```
if (Meteor.user()) {
    // do stuff
}
else {
    $('body').html('<div class="error">You must be logged in to use this application!</div>');
}
```